# Have a Spritekit display a Integer thats stored in a Variable

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

So I'm having difficulty trying to do something that should be easy, clearly I don't see whats wrong.
This is the code:

```
import SpriteKit
var money = "0"
class GameScene: SKScene {
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    let moneyLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"Times New Roman")
    moneyLabel.text = money;
    moneyLabel.fontSize = 14;
    moneyLabel.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
    self.addChild(moneyLabel)

}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
   /* Called when a touch begins */

    for touch in touches {

        money + 1
    }
}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}
```

}

What this is suppose to do is have a label display a Variable, and when the user touches the screen the variable changes by 1, going up by 1 each time its pressed. The Label is suppose to change with the variable.
How do I make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The problem

You are simply adding `1` to `money`

```
money + 1
```

This code:

1. does not change the `money` property
2. does not change the text in you `moneyLabel`
3. is illegal since you cannot sum a `String` and an `Int`

### Solution

This code should do the job

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    private var money = 0 {
        didSet {
            self.moneyLabel?.text = money.description
        }
    }
    private var moneyLabel : SKLabelNode?

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {         
        let moneyLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"Times New Roman")
        moneyLabel.text = money.description
        moneyLabel.fontSize = 14
        moneyLabel.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        self.addChild(moneyLabel)
        self.moneyLabel = moneyLabel
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        money += touches.count
    }
}
```

### Explaination

### 1)

As you can se I added an observer to the `money` property (by the way I made it an `Int` property, not a `String` as in your code!).

```
didSet {
    self.moneyLabel?.text = money.description
}
```

Thanks to the observer, each time the money changes, the `moneyLabel` node is retrieved and it text gets updated.

### 2)

At the end of `didMoveToView` I am saving `moneyLabel` into an instance property

```
self.moneyLabel = moneyLabel
```

so I can easily retrieve (we have seen this in the previous point)

### 3)

Finally in `touchesBegan` I simply increase the `money` property by the number of received touches.

```
money += touches.count
```

Thanks to the observer, each change to the `money` property does trigger an updated to the text inside the `moneyLabel` node.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are three problems here:

1. `money` should be an `Int`, so you can add to it.
2. You haven't actually updated `money` to a new value.
3. You'll need to update the label in addition to `money`.

Take a look at the changes below; each comment explains why a change was necessary:

```
import SpriteKit
class GameScene: SKScene {
    var money = 0 //now an Int, so we can add to it later
    let moneyLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"Times New Roman") //keep this around so we can update it later

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        moneyLabel.text = String(money) //convert money to a String so we can set the text property to it
        moneyLabel.fontSize = 14
        moneyLabel.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        self.addChild(moneyLabel)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
            money = money + 1 //update money to itself + 1
            moneyLabel.text = String(money) //update the label, too
        }
    }
}
```